# How to do join table for has_many through and belongs_to associations in rails?

Tags: ruby, join, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I'm a n00b and still struggling with joins.

I've got two models: Patient and Provider joined through a table Chart.

I used the association "has_many :through" rather than "has_and_belongs_to_many" because i need to have another column added to the Chart table [called patient_mrn] which i cannot do with the "has_and_belongs_to_many" scenario.

What im trying to do is  to show a given patient and all its associated providers [each with its specific  patient_mrn]

The Patient model has:

```
has_many :charts
has_many :providers, :through => :charts
```

The Provider model has:

has_many :charts
  has_many :patients, :through => :charts

and the Chart model has:

```
belongs_to :patient
belongs_to :provider
```

Then in my show action in the patient controller i have:

```
@patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
@providers = Provider.joins(:charts)where(:charts => { :patient_id => @patient.id})
```

And in my patient view i have:

```
<h1>Listing providers</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Provider name</th>
    <th>Patient_mrn</th>
  </tr>

<% @providers.each do |provider| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= provider.name %></td>
    <td><%= provider.chart.patient_mrn %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I realize both the controller action and the view are incorrectly written but cant figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
provider_ids = @patient.charts.select(:provider_id).map(&:provider_id)
@providers = Provider.includes(:charts).find provider_ids
```

In the first line you get the providers of all the patients charts. The map is necessary, because select doesn't return an array of integers but an array of structs with only one member, the provider_id.

In the second line you just select the corresponding providers and include the charts so that you don't have to deal with N+1 queries (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

I can't see anything wrong with your view but i might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Daniel- I appreciate your help!!  I need to really hit the books.